# Bokeh custom tooltips stacking on top of each other

Tags: python, tooltip, bokeh

I have a scatterplot with custom tooltips, when hovering over a bit of the screens where two dots overlap the tooltip for both are drawn on top of one another.

Is there a way to merge the two into one tooltip, as the default tooltip does, or force them to be drawn in non-intersecting ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will never display more then 1 tooltip (Bokeh v1.3.0):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS

data = dict(
        x=[1, 2, 3],
        y=[1, 2, 3],
        color=['red', 'green', 'blue'], ) 

p = figure(tooltips=[('x','@x'),('y', '@y')])
p.circle('x', 'y', color='color', size=10, source = data)

code= '''if (cb_data.index.indices.length > 1) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('bk-tooltip')[0].style.display = 'none'; 
        }'''

p.hover.callback = CustomJS(code = code)

show(p)
```

Disadvantage of this solution is that when all dots exactly overlay each other no tooltips will be shown at all

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of Bokeh 1.4 there is not. There is an [open issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434562/displaying-only-one-tooltip-when-using-the-hovertool-tool) regarding adding a hook for filtering hit-test results, e.g. to limit to only one result or some smaller fixed number of results. But that's a little different from providing a "visual dodge" that will make the whatever results not overlap. If that is your main problem, I would suggest suppressing the tooltips entirely, and using the `callback` on the hover tool to update some other off-plot `Div` with the information in a table or some other suitable condensed representation.