# Python Bokeh HoverTool avoiding display NaN

Tags: python, bokeh, geojson

I have used GeoJSONDataSource (converted from a geopandas) to display ALL the world map in my bokeh figure.

```
geosourceword = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = json_data)
standardfig.patches('xs','ys', source = geosourceword,fill_color = {'field':'deaths', transform':color_mapper})
```

Then I use

```
hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips = [ ('location', '@location'), ('# of deaths', '@deaths')])
```

to display over a location the number of deaths. Since, in my data, some country have deaths = NaN I don't want to display them (for instance in this picture I don't want to display Turkey). Any idea how I can proceed ?
[image]

Comment: You would use `CustomJSHover` to return the empty string (or whatever) for nan values, i..e a special case of the other linked question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62601527/3406693 is also relevant

Comment: CustomJSHover and the link help me a lot thanks. I would like to recommand also this post https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/how-to-create-a-conditional-custom-hover-tool-for-a-holoviews-plot/311