# Displaying only one tooltip when using the hovertool in Bokeh

Tags: python, css, hover, tooltip, bokeh

This is my first stackoverflow question so I apologize for the duplicate post; I don't have the reputation to comment on the [original thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434562/displaying-only-one-tooltip-when-using-the-hovertool-tool) and wasn't sure how else to ask this question.

I have a [plot with a hover tooltip](https://faculty.weber.edu/cariefrantz/GSL/GSL_elevation.html) that frequently displays a long list of returned values. I just want one (any one) to be displayed if there are overlapping values.

[Screenshot of bokeh plot with many hover tooltips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq6uX.png)

I've tried several of the CSS solutions posted on the [original thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434562/displaying-only-one-tooltip-when-using-the-hovertool-tool), but still get multiple tooltips displayed. I'm not sure if I'm implementing the code snippets wrong, or if the solutions are no longer working.

[Screenshot of basic plot from the original post showing the undesired behavior of multiple hover tooltips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpYre.png)

I'm using bokeh 2.3.3 and Chrome. Basic code example is below, and the final project I'm trying to get working is [here](https://faculty.weber.edu/cariefrantz/GSL/GSL_elevation.html).

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, Range1d

custom_hover = HoverTool()

custom_hover.tooltips = """
    <style>
        div.bk-tooltip.bk-right>div.bk>dif:not(:first-child) {
            display:none !important;
            }
        div.bk-tooltip.bk-left>div.bk>dif:not(:first-child) {
            display:none !important;
            }
    </style>


    <b>X: </b> @x <br>
    <b>Y: </b> @y
"""

p = figure(tools=[custom_hover]) #Custom behavior

p.circle(x=[0.75,0.75,1.25,1.25], y=[0.75,1.25,0.75,1.25], size=230, color='red', fill_alpha=0.2)
p.y_range = Range1d(0,2)
p.x_range = Range1d(0,2)

show(p)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The solution below allows only one visible tooltip. This can be changed by modifying the parameter `num`.

This solution was tested with `Bokeh 2.3.2`.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, Range1d, CustomJSHover
output_notebook()

p = figure(tools='')
p.circle(x=[0.75,0.75,1.25,1.25], y=[0.75,1.25,0.75,1.25], size=230, color='red', fill_alpha=0.2)
p.y_range = p.x_range = Range1d(0,2)

t = """
<div @x{custom}>
    <b>X: </b> @x <br>
    <b>Y: </b> @y
</div>
"""

# define how many tooltips you want to show as maximum
num = 1

f = CustomJSHover(code=f"""
special_vars.indices = special_vars.indices.slice(0,{num})
return special_vars.indices.includes(special_vars.index) ? " " : " hidden "
""")

p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=t, formatters={'@x': f}))

show(p)
```